# qmake : warning: No rule to make target Stop

Tags: qt, qmake

I came across lots of similar posts, but none of them helped me.

I have a project which has an app and test. Both App and test depends on a common lib (which is a submodule of the app). Here is my project structure.

```
|
|_ _Application.pro
|_ _App/app.pro
|_ _lib/lib.pro
|_ _TestSuite/
             |_ _Test.pro
```

```
#Application.pro 


TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS +=  app \
            lib

#subdirs
lib.file = $${PWD}/lib/lib.pro
app.file = $${PWD}/App/app.pro

#dependecies
app.depends  =  lib

QMAKE_CLEAN += $${OUT_PWD}/Makefile*
```

```
#Test.pro 


TEMPLATE = subdirs
SUBDIRS +=  Test \
            lib

#subdirs
lib.file = $${PWD}/../lib/lib.pro
app.file = $${PWD}/TestSuite/Test.pro

#dependecies
Test.depends  =  lib

QMAKE_CLEAN += $${OUT_PWD}/Makefile*
```

The application compiles fine, but when I run make on test it throws **No rule to make target lib.pro needed by Test.pro Stop** error.

If I copy the lib files under TestSuite then it works perfectly. So is it mandatory that **subdirs** should a subdirectory of the current application?

Answer (score 1):

Although I can't seem to find it in the documentation at the moment, I at least found a [bug report](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-65362) that states that .pro files using the `subdirs` template should not use directories that point upward in the directory structure. Your subdirs .pro file should be the root of your directory tree.

```
|
|_ _Application.pro
|_ _Test.pro
|_ _App/
        |_ _app.pro
|_ _lib/
        |_ _lib.pro
```

**EDIT:** Here's the relevant [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#subdirs) stating that:

> It is strongly recommended that you specify only paths in the current project's parent directory or its subdirectories.

Comment: From the documentation: "It is strongly recommended that you specify only paths in the current project's parent directory or its subdirectories."

Comment: Thanks @Jens, if you have a link, I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-variable-reference.html#subdirs

Comment: Thanks, I had looked at that, but kept glossing over it.

Comment: One solution I found is to create symblink for those libs under Test folder